# Strange Error changing ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I got a strange error in my app. ( Maybe Xcode bug).

In my App I have a `UITabBarController` as initial viewcontroller.
One of my UIViewController connected with tabbarcontroller have an UIButton where I want change viewcontroller on click. So using Storyboard I have used the show feature but when I press the button this is the error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view 
controller with identifier 'UIViewController-ned-kA-ouy''**

I've search on stackoverflow and tried to fix my issue adding a Storyboard ID but nothing is changed.
I've tried to create a new project and do the same. And it's work without anything. So, whats is happening?

Xcode Version 7.2

Comment: Just search UIViewController-ned-kA-ouy in xcode to know where its been added in code. The view controller's identifier added in storyboard needs to be same that's been assigned while allocating viewcontroller's object.

Comment: I don't have added that UIViewController @PareshNavadiya

Answer (score 0):

I simply tried to copy and paste in another directory the project and now it works.

I hope to help anyone encountered that Xcode BUG.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a xcode bug. You might have changed the type of viewController somewhere while creating the `Main.Storyboard`

Similar error can be reproduced.

- Create a new project. Delete all view controllers from `Main.Storyboard`.
- Add a UITableViewController to Storyboard and set it to Initial view controller. Add necessary DataSource and Delegate.
- Now try to change the Controller type from UITableViewController to UIViewController.
- If you observe now, it'll give something similar kind of error.

Now for your answer. If while copying the code to another project, have you copied the `Main.Storyboard` too. If not, then the creation of Storyboard was proper during the second time. You might have changed the class while creating for the first time.